# How to check server is up?

Tags: java, websphere

I have got a cluster of two server nodes IBM Websphere Application Server on two different physical machine.Can anybody help me with java code to check whether my server instance is running or when one of the server is not up and running?

Comment: doesn't WebSphere ND provide that out of box?

Comment: My objective is to get notified when the server goes down / hung. Can you tell me how WAS ND provide these details?

Comment: Just request a known page and make sure you get it back; trivial cron script or whatever.

Comment: check my answer... hope this is what you want..

Comment: @Pangea may just be referring to the WebSphere Integrated Solutions Console, which provides a graphical, browser-based tool for managing WAS, including the ability to easily see your cluster, server, and application statuses. However, since you requested a Java-based approach and mentioned notifications, you might want to consider the WebSphere administrative Java client as I've described [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8990267/843093).

Answer (score 5):

To do it quickly and portably, you can check for a page if it's served by the server.

For example you can:

```
boolean isAlive = true;
try {
  URL hp = new URL("http://yourserver/TestPage.html"); 
  URLConnection hpCon = hp.openConnection(); 
  // add more checks...
} catch (Exception e) {
  isAlive = false;
}
```

This not much sophisticated method will work with every http server.

Comment: @ Andrea Colleoni : I believe `boolean isAlive = false;` should be `boolean isAlive = true;`.. Right?

Comment: This is missing an hpCon.connect() call to actually establish the connection.

Answer (score 2):

Hope below is what you want...

```
URL url = new URL( "http://google.com/" );
HttpURLConnection httpConn =  (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
httpConn.setRequestMethod( "HEAD" ); 
httpConn.connect();

System.out.println( "google.com : " + httpConn.getResponseCode());
```

or for failure:

```
URL url = new URL( "http://google.com:666/" );
HttpURLConnection httpConn =  (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );
httpConn.setRequestMethod( "HEAD" ); 
try{
    httpConn.connect();
     System.out.println( "google.com : " + httpConn.getResponseCode());
}catch(java.net.ConnectException e){
     System.out.println( "google.com:666 is down ");
}
```

Good Luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you may be looking for is the use of the [WebSphere Thin Administrative Client](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/txml_adminclient.html), which exposes Java APIs and provides access to the WAS [MBeans](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/mbeanDocs/index.html) that allow you to query the status of your servers/applications (along with many other management and monitoring tasks).

First, you'll want to obtain a connection to WAS (the [`AdminClient`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fweb%2Fapidocs%2Fcom%2Fibm%2Fwebsphere%2Fmanagement%2FAdminClient.html)) as follows:

```
Properties clientProps = new Properties();
clientProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE, AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_SOAP);
clientProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, dmgrHostname);
clientProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, dmgrSoapConnectorPort);
if (dmgrIsSecure) {
    clientProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_SECURITY_ENABLED, "true");
    clientProps.setProperty(AdminClient.USERNAME, wasUsername);
    clientProps.setProperty(AdminClient.PASSWORD, wasUserPassword);
}
AdminClient adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(clientProps);
```

Next, you'll want to query for the relevant MBeans, and then perform the relevant operations. In your case, you may be interested in the [ClusterMgr](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fweb%2FmbeanDocs%2FClusterMgr.html) and/or [J2EEApplication](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc%2Fweb%2FmbeanDocs%2FJ2EEApplication.html) MBeans. Here is an example that queries for the Cluster's state:

```
AdminClient adminClient = getAdminClient(target);
ObjectName clusterMgr =
    (ObjectName)adminClient.queryNames(
        ObjectName.getInstance("WebSphere:*,type=ClusterMgr"), null).iterator().next();
String state = adminClient.invoke(clusterMgr, "getClusterState",
    new Object[] {clusterName}, new String[] {String.class.getName()});
```

You can invoke further operations as desired, such as querying the individual cluster member's status.

Also, in addition to querying, you can also [register notifications](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/management/AdminClient.html#addNotificationListener(javax.management.ObjectName,%20javax.management.NotificationListener,%20javax.management.NotificationFilter,%20java.lang.Object)) so that your program can be notified when certain events happen, such as a change in state of clusters, servers, or applications.

Answer (score 1):

We get the specialized connection for the URL we want using `openConnection()`. It will return a subclass of the abstract class `URLConnection`, depending on the URL's public protocol, for example a `HttpURLConnection`. Then with the method `connect()` opens the communication link

```
private String server = "http://testserver:9086";
try {
    URLConnection hpCon = new URL(SERVER).openConnection();
    hpCon.connect();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Anything you want to do when there is a failure
}
```

Comment: @Vogel612 Code answers are fine. Chillax.

Comment: @Vogel612 Thanks for your feedback. I had the same issue and wanted to share the code, I thought it was clear, but for sure can be clearer. Now I tried to explain a bit the code.