# Test when server is up or down

Tags: java, ssh

I am trying to test for a server if its reachable or not. I am tailing log files from different servers using ssh and connecting to server using java Ganymed from the following web http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/. So I am trying to find a simple way of pinging a server because I want to show the user a list of up and down servers so they know their status when they try to tail log files on the servers.

Any shed of light would is highly appreciated. I also tried using JPingy but I am not sure if it does what I want as I am getting long messages an exception. Is there something I can use to test if some server is reachable so I can update user with its status ? 
The following is the code I use from JPingy example which shows me some odd messages which I don't understand.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    PingArguments arguments = new PingArguments.Builder().url("google.com")
            .timeout(5000).bytes(32).build();

    PingResult results = Ping.ping(arguments, Backend.UNIX);

    System.out.println(results.ttl());
    System.out.println(results.rtt_min());
    System.out.println(results.received());

}
```

}

The exception that I am getting is the following

```
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at com.googlecode.jpingy.UnixPingResult.matchReceived(UnixPingResult.java:52)
at com.googlecode.jpingy.PingResult.<init>(PingResult.java:79)
at com.googlecode.jpingy.UnixPingResult.<init>(UnixPingResult.java:29)
at com.googlecode.jpingy.Ping$Backend$1.getResult(Ping.java:31)
at com.googlecode.jpingy.Ping.ping(Ping.java:59)
at Main.main(Main.java:13) 

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Main.main(Main.java:15)
```

Any kind of help is really appreciated, is it possible to have a true or false returned for connection using some other library ?

Comment: Please add the messages you are getting from JPingy to your question.

Comment: Hi Ireeder, thanx for the quickly reply, I updated with the exception.

Comment: [JPingy only supports Linux and Android](https://code.google.com/p/jpingy/downloads/detail?name=jpingy0_1-alpha.jar).  I suspect you're using it on Windows - I get the same error as you when I run your code on Windows.

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks for the reply, now I get why there is no Backend.Windows argument because I was busy fidgeting with that, thanks a lot for the reply, you are right I am using windows, so there is no other library I can use which is simple to test reachability of server in java

Comment: I'm not aware of any Java library that can do pings.  The usual way to do this on Windows is to run `ping.exe` in a subprocess, but that approach can hardly be described as simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following question, which seems to be similar to yours.

[How to check server is up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988953/how-to-check-server-is-up)

Comment: Hi Ederollora, thank you for the quick reply, I will go through the link and will come back to you to tell you if it works for or not.