# WAS service status is not correct in services

Tags: java, windows, websphere

I am trying to stop and start Websphere Application Server (WAS) service from Task Manager--> Services. Service is started and java.exe process is showing in task manager but in services, the status of WAS service is stopped. I can't reboot because it's on client machine. Please tell me what is causing this and how can I resolve it.

Comment: Do you know how it was started? Perhaps it was not started as a service.

Answer (score 0):

you can try two ways 
1)Use http connection to check admin console is up
2)Use wsadmin java client to check status More  pointer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988953/how-to-check-server-is-up)